# How do I prove that for a random variable $X$, we have $P(X \le a) \le p$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Specifically, suppose that $X$ is a random variable with properties $\mathrm{Var}(X) = 9$, $\mu = \mathbb{E}(X) = 2$, and $\max(X) \le 10$, (or $P(X \ge 10) = 0$). How can I prove the following?

$$P(X \le 1) \le \frac{8}{9}$$

Comment: With max(x)\leq10 do you mean that P(X>10)=0?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $p:=P(X\le 1)$, we have $2=\Bbb E[X]\le p\cdot 1+(1-p)\cdot 10$, hence $p\le \frac 89$.

Answer (score 1):

Because

$$E(X) \le 1\cdot 8/9 + 10\cdot 1/9 = 18/9 = 2$$

If the probability is higher than $8/9$ then the $E(X)$ must be smaller than $2$, contradiction